# How to share business logic for angular2 web app and ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have developed a web app in angular2 and I am currently using [Angular Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) for development. I have a folder called `Shared/Business` which has all the business related logic in it. Now I am developing an ionic2 mobile app. It is a totally different project where I would like to reuse the business logic. Rather than copying the business logic folder in my mobile app folder, I would like to read them from a common place. Can somebody please tell me how can I reuse my code? What changes do I need to make in the existing project to achieve this?

Comment: is shared logic in TS or pure JS?

Comment: It is In TypeScript

Comment: good then.. Directly import it using import statement. At the end the build system will pick it from that common location while compile into a single js file

Comment: Thank you.But is it possible to use an project folder setup with angular cli and place mobile and web related code in it.

Comment: yes of-course.. you need to write a gulp task for that.. simple

Comment: Cool Thank You.. Have a nice day